# ¿Cómo aplicar un Z scored por grupo?

Tags: r

Quiero obtener z score agrupando por groups. Este es mi código:

```
data<-read.csv("C:/Users/usuario/Desktop/Tandas/TANDA JAPON/metabolomics/data/fwdreandres/R_PCA_tapR_sini.csv",sep=";",row.names = 1)

head(data)
```

La foto adjunta es una representacion de mis datos pues los mismos son demasiado largos como para postear

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
data<-scale(data,center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

Este código calcula z score pero sin tener en cuenta los grupos. Me podeis ayudar?

Comment: Hola. Este foro sólo usa español; por favor, traduce tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Una forma bien simple en este caso es apoyarse en las rutinas de  `dplyr`, algo así:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(var1 = scale(var1),
           var2 = scale(var2),
           var3 = scale(var3),
           var4 = scale(var4))
```

O bien

```
data %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(matches('var')), list(scaled = scale))
```

Básicamente:

- Agrupamos por la variable `group` mediante el verbo `group_by`
- Por cada grupo, calculamos una nueva variable con el mismo nombre de la original aplicando `scale()` al grupo
- La versión con `mutate_at()` te aplica `scale` a todas las columnas con el nombre `var*` y crea una nueva versión con el nombre `*_scaled`
- Recuerda que puedes instalar `dplyr` con `install.packages("dplyr")` o `install.packages("tidyverse")` que agrega varios paquetes muy útiles

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!